# how to use jsonbuilder with collections?

Tags: groovy

I need to create a json message like this:

```
{
  success:true,
  count:3,
  data: [
    {id:1},
    {id:2},
    {id:3}
  ]
}
```

I have tried this

```
import groovy.json.*

def tasks = [1, 2,3]
def json = new JsonBuilder()

json{
  success(true)
  count(tasks.size())
  data {
    tasks.each {
      data(
        id: it        
      )
    }
  }
}

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())
```

but it doesn't work. Can somebody show me how to make it work?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'd recommend transforming the tasks list into a list of the form `[[id: 1], [id: 2], [id: 3]]` and then "jsonizing" it:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def tasks = [1, 2, 3]
def json = new JsonBuilder()

json{
  success(true)
  count(tasks.size())
  data(tasks.collect {[id: it]})
}

println json.toPrettyString()
```

I usually prefer generating the data structures in Groovy first (e.g. lists, maps) and then convert them to JSON, that way I usually have more control over the data that is going to be serialized and I don't need to include logic on the serialization code.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def tasks = [1, 2, 3]

def data = [
  success: true,
  count: tasks.size(),
  data: tasks.collect {[id: it]}
]

def json = new JsonBuilder(data)
println json.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: hey what is that groovy syntax: `json{...}`? curly bracket immediately after variable name? new to groovy...

Comment: @Mahesha999 the `json` object is of a type that can be called. Doing `json{...}` is the same as `json({...})`, which is calling the `json` object with a block of code as a parameter.

Comment: I must be missing something basic from groovy. What does it mean by "type that can be called"? We usually call methods in Java not the type instance / object / variable directly.

Comment: @Mahesha999 in Groovy an object is "callable" if it responds to a `call` message. An example of callable objects are [closures](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) themselves. You can use the `call` method explicitly, like `someClosure.call(42)`, or just call it like a function `someClosure(42)`. In this case, `json` is an instance of JsonBuilder, which also [defines a `call` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton @epidemian this has been super helpful!